# Change "on-topic?" to "belongs?"

Tags: feature-request, area-51, terminology

Something can be on-topic and still not appropriate for the site.  This [initially confused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52164/should-subjective-example-questions-be-marked-cw/52170#52170) me, and a handful of my first 10 votes got switched after reconsidering what is being asked.  Therefore, *is this on-topic?* should instead read ***is it appropriate?***

For example, *what is the best X?* is clearly on-topic for an "Xoverflow" proposal, even though it would/should be closed and discouraged.  If the site is not about such vague, subjective, open-ended questions, we want to clearly mark that question as inappropriate (but softly, not a hammer like "will you buyz my V1AGRA" would be inappropriate to propose in the first place).

Another way to word it is ***do we want it on the proposed site?***, but that's clearly too long.  Is there a better way to phrase that sentiment than what I've come up with?

*Forty-five minutes later:* I *just* noticed the title text on the "yes" and "no" buttons.  Yes.. I should've known to look, but I can't have been the only one that missed it.  It gives a better phrase: ***does it belong?***

#### Update including [3rd voting option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52610/)

- belongs on site
- doesn't belong
- bad example

Instead of the current:

- great on-topic example
- great off-topic example
- not a good example