# The graphics of the new voting system need improvement

Tags: feature-request, voting, area-51, user-interface

Apart from its working, on which I already disagreed enough, I just find the new three buttons "great on-topic" / "great off-topic" / "not good" system to be visually awful; the three of them are just too *plain* and too *similar*, almost undistinguishable if you haven't already voted on one of them.

Am I the only one that thinks these graphics need improvement?

[image: screenshot]

I think some colors and arrows would help a lot here.

Comment: The graphics of this feature-request are TERRIBLE! It needs a screenshot. With *circles* that illuminate the problem. *Hand-drawn* circles. With *drop-shadows*.

Comment: @Shog9: meme-compliant picture added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the same colours as the .selected class, without the bold - it's still clear which option you have selected.

[image]

Comment: If someone with lots-o-rep could inline the image for me it would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are the drop-shadows?!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a right arrow for on topic, and a left arrow for off-topic. The NaGE vote could then be a down arrow. Kinda like this:

```
 <      >
off    on

    \/
   NaGE
```

Answer (score 0):

We would love to see suggestions for how to improve this.  I agree it's not great, but we went through a lot of options and decided to err on the side of explaining too much, which is why it's so wordy and there's not much room to make it look nice.

Comment: ["belongs" / "doesn't belong"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52203/change-on-topic-to-belong) / "bad example". The tooltips seem fine to me; wordiness there isn't necessarily a bad thing.  Using "belongs on site" / "doesn't belong" could be closer in visual length.

Comment: What about this? :-p http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/8577/votingp.jpg

Comment: @massimo: That's interesting: can you vote up/down *and* vote on-/off-topic? Can I weight my on-/off-topic votes? What if you had unlimited on-/off-topic votes, but only 10 upvotes...

Comment: @The Cat: that's exactly what I'm proposing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52501/proposal-for-a-new-voting-system-on-area-51-now-with-pictures

Answer (score -1):

The OP *gave* some good suggestions - colors and arrows. Put an up-arrow or hat on the on-topic, down-arrow on the off-topic. Or maybe a smiley/frowney face for each. :)

Comment: It's important to avoid subliminal suggestions on whether "on-topic" is good and "off-topic" is bad.. proposals need *both,* and if I vote "off-topic", that is a *compliment* to the poster.  (Yes, I have an issue with using green for "on-topic", too.)

Comment: This is the fundamental flaw of this voting system... associating on- and off-topic status with question *quality*. But let not me start again on this, please... :-/