# Area 51 voting options should be more different

Tags: feature-request, voting, area-51

The three vote options on Area 51 are too similar. The text on the options ends with the same word, and there are no colors defining them before you vote.

I just realized that I have been voting on 'not a good example' instead of 'off-topic example' because I assumed the order of the options wrong, and there were no obvious visual cues to tell me that I was assuming incorrectly.

I propose that you change the options to:

- On Topic
- Off Topic
- Bad Example

Those three are clearly different. I would also suggest some color cues or images to help differentiate the options.

Comment: Though the on & off topic examples are meant to be exemplary, so the options need to have the word "great" (or equivalent) in them.

Comment: @Chris I was thinking about that.  I think the fact that you only get 5(?) votes helps get that point across.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The graphics of the new voting system need improvement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52610/the-graphics-of-the-new-voting-system-need-improvement)

Comment: @Jon He is complaining that they are ugly.  I'm complaining that they do not function well.

Comment: @Justin: After reading both questions again, they sound the same to me. IMO, this should be an answer in that question.

Comment: @ire You telling us that you don't store what you see in a FIFO format? (You missed a queue, by the way)

Comment: @ccomet - well spotted!

Comment: @ire Thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

- I'd totally answer this sh*t!!
- No he didn't! I'd vote to close and flag 3 times!
- This "person" doesn't even know what he's talking about

Answer (score 3):

I agree. I know they are really trying to encourage people to focus on "great example", but it's redundant and, I believe, no longer necessary.

If "Bad Example" is unpalatable (it may be since they chose "Not a good..." rather than "Bad...") then `Poor Example` may be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: How about `It's Crap`?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the names cause confusion, and proposed a naming solution here:

[Why no one rational will post "off-topic" questions (and how to possibly fix it):](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52645/why-no-one-rational-will-post-off-topic-questions-and-how-to-possibly-fix-it)